# React JS: How to render new component on scrolling?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, scroll, frontend, clone

Basically, I want to mimic the home page of the https://www.criterion.com/ site. You can see that on scrolling new components are being loaded. I want to stack the components one after another:

```
 <Background Media-1 />
 <Background Media-2 />
 <Background Media-3 />
 <Background Media-4 />
```

One loading the site, the user must see Background Media-1. On scrolling, he must see the media-2, media-3 and so on. I want to know how can I implement this scroll bar and the buttons to toggle between components? Also note that that the scrollbar automatically resets when you put it in a position showing half of each of adjacent components.

In short, what are the tools, libraries required to mimic Criterion Home page with React JS.

Answer (score 0):

For example, using this to render items only on visible area https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-scroll-viewport